# [SOLVED] rviz not showing 16 bits-per-pixel, single channel depth images

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am playing a bag of 16 bits-per-pixel depth and 8 bit rgb images.
While playing the bag, I can extract both the rgb and the depth images into files (verifying that the data is ok)
(I used the thread [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/313164/create-a-bag-out-of-16-bit-images/) to create and extract the depth images)

The way the depth image is stored in the bag is by using a python script that uses the PIL package to read a pgm image from file into a PIL object, serialize the object data into byte array (using io.BytesIO()), and save the byte array in PPM format.

**In rviz I can view the rgb image, but I cannot view the depth image.**

rviz issues an error message:

```
[ WARN] [1548110467.614542827]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 283)
[ERROR] [1548110467.614620078]: Error loading image: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 283)
```

The transport Hint in rviz is set to "raw" and I cannot change it.

Thanks,

Avner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313323/%5Bsolved%5D-rviz-not-showing-16-bits-per-pixel,-single-channel-depth-images/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
I would actually recommend to post your `edit1` as an answer and then accept your own answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of it).

That would much more clearly show that your question was answered.

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-01-29**:
Done. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the way that the depth image is stored in the bag in the python script, to use cv_bridge instead of using the PIL.

```
im_depth = cv2.imread(depth_img, -1)
bridge = CvBridge()
# passthrough honors the original image encoding (mono16)
image_message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(im_depth, encoding="passthrough")
image_message.header.stamp = Stamp
image_message.header.frame_id = "camera"
bag.write('camera/depth/image', image_message, Stamp)
```

After doing this, I can see the depth image in rviz.

p.s. as a sanity test, I extracted the files from the the bag and verified that they are actual 16 bit images (image type is 16 bit and pixel values are greater than 255)

I used the solution to execute rtabmap on a bag with rgb and 16 bit depth images. See [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/313325/rtabmap-fails-to-run-a-bag-of-depth-and-rgdb-images/?answer=313701#post-id-313701)

---

Originally posted by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) with karma: 96 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ cannot view 16 bit images natively. You'll have to convert them to an 8 bit format.

There are various ways to do this. A simple method is to normalise the depth image to the range 0-255 and changed to an 8 bit image. Or a more meaningful conversion would be adding a color bar and scale.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-01-22**:
Thanks for your answer. After using cv_bridge to add the 16 bit depth image into the bag, I can now see it in rviz without any special further adjustments. Does this mean that actually, rviz can handle 16 bit images? (maybe it does scale it down internally to 8 bit per pixel)